# Can XSL use only PHP function that returns a string?

Tags: php, arrays, function, xslt, php-extension

Why this is not working? Can XSL use only PHP function that returns a string?

```
  <xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(TipoImm, '/')) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:element name="test">
      <xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('implode',
            (php:function('explode', TipoImm, '/')), '-')" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Is the problem that you are trying to pass a PHP function call to `implode` when it expects a XPath expression?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can also return DOMDocument or basically any DOMNode derivative.